# Overriding HomeKey in Android JB and above

Tags: android

How can we override the home key in Android JB and above.I have searched a lot of threads but those doesn't work for Latest android versions.Also this is possible as I have checked in some apps available in Play Store such as "Active LockScreen".

Comment: not possible to override home key

Comment: @Raghunandan ... yes it's definitely possible ...please check this app "Active LockScreen" on Play store

Comment: not possible without a workaround. implement a home screen

Comment: @Raghunandan I have already checked the link for whicj you have duplicated my question.It doesn't work.

Comment: @ddnith A quick question, do you just want to detect if user has pressed the`Home` key and do something on the key being pressed(and app goes to background)? Or you want to change its functionality completely? Or some other stuff. I understand that you want to override it. But what exactly you want to do with it?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I want to change the functionality.I want to keep my activity in front even if HOME key is pressed.Actually I want to implement mu own lock screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now I have found the way by making my app Launcher and let the user chose if he/she want to disable the home key functionality while App is running.While App is not in foreground My App fires Intent DEFAULT_LAUNCHER_INTENT to display the DEFAULT Launcher.
I'll post if find another work around without making the app Launcher.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot override the home button for security reason. it is the only way a user can always leave an app

Comment: yes we can.. there is some way... check this app "Active LockScreen"

Comment: the only way is to make your app a launcher

Comment: which is exactly what that app is

Comment: @JosephEarl How can we make our app lock Screen?

Comment: @tyczj making an app Launcher is not an option.If I make my app Launcher it will ask to chose bw default launcher and my app each time user press the home key

Comment: what you want to do is not an option really, there is a reason why it cant be done

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864300/create-a-lock-screen-of-my-own